# Add HTML Template to Textarea with jQuery & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I am trying to create a template which will allow someone to click a button that will instantly create a template into a text area, wiping out all the data in there.

PHP:

```
    function get_jquery_templates() {
    require('MYSQLI CONNECTION');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM **TEMPLATE DATABASE**";

    $result = $mysqli->query($query); 
    echo "$(document).ready(function(){";
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $category_name = $row['category_name'];
        $short_name = $row['short_name'];

        echo "$('#" . $short_name . "').click(function(){
               $('#ckeditor').html('" . $row['template'] . "');
            });\n";
    }
    echo "});";
}
```

jQuery from "View Source":

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../../../assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>                             <!-- Load jQuery -->
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#test1').click(function(){
               $('#ckeditor').html('Test 1');
            });
$('#test2').click(function(){
               $('#ckeditor').html('Test 2');
            });
});</script>
```

HTML:

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Templates</label>
<div class=\col-sm-8"><input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="test1" value="Test 1" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="test2" value="Test 2" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-12"><textarea name="ckeditor" id="" cols="100" rows="20" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
```

My console via Firebug isn't showing an issue and using jFiddle is also not working.

Comment: Are you using ckeditor plugin ?

Comment: Yes I am it was provided in the template

Comment: I am not sure where is your ckeditor instance init, but if you are using it,
I think the right way to pass html string to ckeditor is using setData method, 
example `CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.setData('html here');
`
Read more [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData)

Comment: You are a legend @3d7, you have just saved me hours and hours of searching for an answer to no avail. Thank you!

Comment: I will post it as an answer, please vote and choose correct 
I am very happy I helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CKEDITOR, 
I think the right way to pass html string to ckeditor is using setData method, example

```
CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.setData('html here');
```

Read More [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData)